# jQuery Multi Step Form Animation Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with this form. Here is my [jsFiddle file.](http://jsfiddle.net/T8WRM/)

Here is my JS

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formToWizard = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({
            submitButton: ""
        }, options);

        var element = this;

        var steps = $(element).find("fieldset");
        var count = steps.size();
        var submmitButtonName = "#" + options.submitButton;
        $(submmitButtonName).hide();

        // 2
        steps.each(function(i) {
            $(this).wrap("<div id='step" + i + "'></div>");
            $(this).append("<p id='step" + i + "commands'></p>");



            if (i == 0) {
                createNextButton(i);
                selectStep(i);
            }
            else if (i == count - 1) {
                $("#step" + i).hide();
                createPrevButton(i);
            }
            else {
                $("#step" + i).hide();
                createPrevButton(i);
                createNextButton(i);
            }
        });

        function createPrevButton(i) {
            var stepName = "step" + i;
            $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Prev'>Back</a>");

            $("#" + stepName + "Prev").bind("click", function(e) {
                $("#" + stepName).hide();
                $("#step" + (i - 1)).show(function() {
                    $('.slide').animate({
                        left: "0"
                    }, 500);
                });
                $(submmitButtonName).hide();
                selectStep(i - 1);
            });
        }

        function createNextButton(i) {
            var stepName = "step" + i;
            $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Next' class='next'>Next</a>");

            $("#" + stepName + "Next").bind("click", function(e) {
                $("#" + stepName).hide();
                $("#step" + (i + 1)).show(function() {
                    $('.slide').animate({
                        left: "0"
                    }, 500);
                });
                if (i + 2 == count) $(submmitButtonName).show();
                selectStep(i + 1);
            });
        }

        function selectStep(i) {
            $("#steps li").removeClass("current");
            $("#stepDesc" + i).addClass("current");
        }

    }
        })(jQuery);

    $("#SignupForm").formToWizard({ submitButton: 'SaveAccount' })
​
```

What i want it to do is slide in from the left(*left to right*) when i click next and when i click 'back' i want it to slide left(*right to left*).

Where i am doing my animation

> $("#step" + (i + 1)).show(function() {
>                           $('.slide').animate({
>                               left: "0"
>                           }, 500);
>                       });

Something similar to [8 Tracks](http://8tracks.com) when you select a genre and then click back.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Just an observation, thats a lot of script to make a div slide...

Comment: its a multi step form. i want it to slide to the next step when i click next. @VIDesignz

Answer (score 1):

To see something coming from the right, it actually needs to be there ! What was missing in your code was the element going on the right side :

```
$("#" + stepName).animate({
    left: "100%"
}, 0);
```

Here is the jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/T8WRM/16/

I left the animate function if you'd want your previous element to move, to do so remove .show() and .hide to see the full movement

EDIT :

To be clear about the slider thing, it does not work like this, meaning you should get views aside (most of the time by absolute positionning them on different z-indexs) and move either all of them through a viewholder or through a combination (prev,next,current)

Comment: This is what I thought at first too, but take a look at his example. He wants the two different pages to move in unison with a uniform gap between them.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. one thing i noticed due to my poor knowledge of `.animate`. i noticed that when i click next and back my animation isn't as smooth as how you did it. the input fields start animating from the top left to the right. how can i avoid this? and have it just animate from the center left to the right? @jonBreizh

Comment: @ BeEasy, the appearance from top left is because of show and hide, when using these methods, the element doesn't only change display (display:none), it actually doesn't but is clipped to a 0 width and height. so when you show it, it regains it's height and width, that's the weird animation

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at your example. You're tackling this problem the wrong way.

Take a look at the markup on 8tracks. the 3 slides are never made `hidden` with css or by a jQuery `.hide()`. They are "hidden" because there is another div in front of them, so they are "hidden" to the user, but are technically visible.

Instead of sliding the individual "pages", they slide all 3 pages as a unit. However, the div which covers the previously "hidden" pages stays static.

Imagine your form pages are 3 pieces of paper on an assembly line and you are looking down with eagle-vision. You can only see one paper at a time (because there is a divider blocking the others). When you want to move to the next page, you press "next" on the assembly line. All 3 pages move one slot to the left, and you can now see the next page.